# The space of arrival for Fourier transform.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

If $f\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$, let $\hat f$ be the **Fourier transform** of $f$
$$\hat f=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) e^{-ixt} dt, \ \ (-\infty<x<\infty)$$
we can see Fourier transform as an application by $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ to another space. Usually, who is this space? I imagine that, under certain conditions, it may be (for example) the Paley-Wiener space. Who can tell me something more?

Comment: in my filed, x=f, and f is frequency- so , FT provide anlysis in frequency domain

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've evidently heard about the Paley-Weiner theorem but you don't believe it or something... ?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich. I am not prepared on this subject, I tried to read something but to no avail. I do not know the theorem that you quote.

Comment: @Lely I said that this space is usually frequency

Comment: See Rudin _Real and Complex Analysis_...

Comment: see this : Signals and Systems (2nd Edition),  Alan V. Oppenheim

Comment: This field in mathematics has been created by an engineer, fourier the great:D

Comment: @Cardinal : Fourier was a Mathematician by training, Physicist, Engineer, Egyptologist, Government Official under Napoleon. Several other titles apply, too. Fourier's advisor was the Mathematician and Astronomer Lagrange. Lagrange's advisor was Euler.

Comment: @TrialAndError it supposed to be a joke, I know this french man ! A real engineer is the translation of mathematician by training, well ? :)

Comment: @Cardinal : You should not call him French; that's a terrible thing to say about Fourier, almost as insulting as calling him a Mathematician. :)